# Solve in rational numbers, the equation, $x\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}=58$

Tags: functions

Solve in rational numbers, the equation,
$$x\lfloor x\rfloor\{x\}=58$$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\{x\}$ are the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and the fractional part of $x$ respectively.

> I tried to make an equation like:
> $$(a+b)ab=58$$
> where $a=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $b=\{x\}$ and giving the restrictions that $a$ is an **integer** and $b$ is a **rational number** such that $0≤b<1$.

> Then I made a quadratic equation over $b$ and used the famous quadratic formula. But everything became complex (not the mathematical 'complex') and so please help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a hint: $$x=n+p \text{    where    } n=\lfloor x\rfloor\\
\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor=(n+p)-n=p$$ so 
$$x\lfloor x\rfloor \{x\}=56\\(n+p)np=56\\$$

Comment: If you try to plot the function ... this equation has infinite solution...https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0wggfa1r53

Answer (score 7):

Let $b=p/q$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$ and $0 \le p<q$. The equation becomes $$(qa+p)ap=58q^2$$

Since $\gcd((qa+p)p,q)=\gcd(p^2,q)=1$ we have $q^2|a$. Write $a=kq^2(k \in \Bbb{Z})$(apparently $k \ne 0$) and we get $$(kq^3+p)kp=58$$

Then $p|58$. Moreover, $|kq^3+p| \ge |k|q^3-p \ge (p+1)^3-p>p$, thus $p$ is the smaller positive factor of $58 \Rightarrow p=1,2$. A simple discussion will conclude that $p=2,q=3,k=1,a=9$, so the solution is $x=29/3$.

Comment: Do you mean that os only solution  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes. The poster seeks rational solution.

Comment: @Khosrotash And your comments to the poster are invalid since the poster already did the job you "hint".

Comment: @NeatMath No, $k$ could be minus.

Comment: I could not understand the inequality part.

Comment: @RupamMaiti Can you get that $|k| \ge 1$ and $q \ge p+1$?

Comment: @Zerox, I can get it